# MySQL Inner Join Issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm having a bit of a problem with a MySQL query in my PHP. I'm assuming it's down to a simple syntax issue and am hoping somebody here can help me out.

The query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `Threads` INNER JOIN `Categories` 
WHERE  `Threads`.`Category_ID` = `Categories`.`Category_ID` 
  AND    `Categories`.`Category_Name` = 'General'
```

The purpose of the query is to allow for the row count of threads within a forum category to be used.

It seems that the first half of the query is working correctly but the part after the `AND` statement is not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error you receive? You should move the first part of the `WHERE`-clause to an `ON`-clause for your join.

Comment: Remember, MySQL quotes are your friend. It doesn't just make the query look clearer, it also can bring some performance and help avoid conflicts if you are poorly inspired when naming fields and tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `Threads` `t`
INNER JOIN `Categories` `c` ON `t`.`Category_ID` = `c`.`Category_ID`
WHERE `c`.`Category_Name` = 'General'
```

Comment: @tntu: It is not necessary to escape everything ;)

Comment: Yes, but in programming consistency is very important and can help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `Threads` AS `t`, `Categories` AS `c` 
WHERE  `t`.`Category_ID` = `c`.`Category_ID` 
  AND    `c`.`Category_Name` = 'General'
```

Comment: This type of `JOIN` has the lowest performance. Joins should always be done based `ON` a integer field common to both tables.